# Get certain attributes from an Eloquent model when converting to an Array in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-5.3

I have a model (e.g. `User`).

I can easily convert it to an array like so:

```
$user->toArray()
```

However, this gives all the attributes. I only want attributes `x`, `y` and `z`.

We can use the `hidden` and `visible` attributes of the model to hide/show values, as described here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-serialization#hiding-attributes-from-json

However, I don't want to use this because this is more of a one off situation. Not a regular occurrence.

The `pluck` method is ideal, but this only applies to Collections, not Models.

Comment: you can return [$user->x, $user->y, $user->z], or customize with local scopes https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#local-scopes

Answer (score 3):

You can override the `toArray()` method, and allow it to take an array of the fields you'd like returned.

```
public function toArray(array $fields = [])
{
    // Get the full, original array.
    $original = parent::toArray();

    // If no fields are specified, return the original array.
    // This ensures that all existing code works the same
    // way as before.
    if (empty($fields)) {
        return $original;
    }

    // Return an array containing only those fields specified
    // by the input parameter.
    return array_intersect_key($original, array_flip($fields));
}
```

With this method overridden in your User model, you can now have the following code:

```
// Will return an array with all the fields.
$full = $user->toArray();

// Will return an array with only x, y, and z fields.
$partial = $user->toArray(['x', 'y', 'z']);
```

NB: Since this calls the parent `toArray()` method, this overridden method will still respect the `$hidden` attribute. So, if `y` hidden, and you call `$user->toArray(['x', 'y', 'z']);`, the resulting array will not contain the `y` value.

Answer (score 1):

You can now use the [`only`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-only) method, I believe available since at least Laravel 5, which already returns an array:

```php
$user->only(['x', 'y', 'x']);
```

OR

```php
$user->only('x', 'y', 'x');
// ['x' => 1, 'y' => 2, 'x' => 3]
```